# how is livestream.com displaying the archived video(s)?

Tags: video

**I am not talking about their live streams. I am talking about their stored videos.**

Here is a sample video:

http://www.livestream.com/laleysports1/video?clipId=pla_b13fd92c-be95-46a8-af5e-100ad9e28cf1

I am using a software VideoCacheView, and it is showing me details about the caches being requested, so for youtube I can see where all the video files are being saved. It is doing the same for livestream.com videos too except no matter what video I play, they all store cache of same size (very small) and none of them work obviously when I try to open them.

What method/programming technique is livestreams.com is using to display their **stored** (not live) videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems livestream does not deliver these stored videos using http...They deliver these videos through [rtmp](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/rtmp.html). Browsers do not store these videos like http (i.e. youtube) ones. And its a bug/unsupported feature of your software VideoCacheView that it can not store these rtmp videos. This is nothing about programming.